# Can I read Ayat al-Kursi in English after salah?

Tags: salat

Assalamu Alaikum wr wb, I just started praying and only the basics so I don't know the arabic words for Ayat al-Kursi which can be read after prayer for great reward. So I was wondering can I just look at the verse on my phone and read it in English or does it have to be read in arabic from memorisation?

Also does it have to be read after the fard prayer or after the extra optional prayers for Dhuhr, Maghrib and Isha?

Comment: Read it after fard prayer and read it in English until you memorize it in arabic and after memorizing read it in arabic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wa Alaikumussalam,

Reading Ayat-Ul-Kursi after a Fard prayer has got great rewards.

It was narrated that Abu Umaamah said: “The Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “Whoever recites Ayatul Kursi immediately after each prescribed prayer, there will be nothing standing between him and his entering Paradise except death.”

So, I encourage you to start with the meaning of the verse and then start memorizing Ayat Ul Kursi. You can also read that verse from your phone.

Regarding your second question, it is recommended after every fard prayer. But it is optional and it is according to your wish.

May Allah Grant You Jannah.

Comment: Jazakallah Khair, ameen and to you to.

Comment: Wa Iyyakum Brother.

Answer (score 1):

WaAlaykumAsSalam,

First of all I would like to begin by congratulating you for making an effort towards Salah. Any step you take towards Allah, Allah takes an even bigger step towards you. May Allah reward you and keep you (and all of us) steadfast in this.

As brother Atif mentioned, yes you are supposed to recite it after the Fard (obligatory) prayers along with other Adhkar - all of which are optional but beneficial.

Regarding the issue of the language of recitation, it is obviously preferable to be recited in Arabic since that is the language Allah revealed it in ([Quran 12:2](https://quran.com/12/2)). And unfortunately no translation of the Quran does justice to the actual depth of meaning of the Quran. If you are a native Arabic speaker or an expert in Arabic, you realize the words in the Quran are not that of mere mortals like us.

Having said that, you can certainly read the translation while you are still memorizing the verse, but my advise would be to read the [transliteration](https://littlemuslimhouse.com/ayatul-kursi-translation-transliteration/) instead (after having read the translation enough times to know what the verse means - which you most probably have already). Alternatively, you could listen to the audio on your phone every time after Salah and recite along - it will make it very easy for you to memorize the verse if you follow this approach.

And Allah Knows Best.

Once again, May Allah reward you, and remember us in your Dua.